# How to get operating system name

Tags: c#, .net, variables, types, compiler-errors

I have this C# code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string os = System.OperatingSystem;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    //..and more
```

and it says that "'System.OperatingSystem' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context (CS0119)".So how to delete this error?

Comment: Just read the error message, it explains *exactly* what's wrong. Just check the type's properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.OperatingSystem` is a type, you couldn't asign it to a variable. What do you want to achieve? Name of running operating system? You could do it with:

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

Comment: Oh man...Thanks a lot...